# Dealing with null character in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open a binary file in VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010), that looks like this:

[image]
The file opens ok with this method:

```
Dim OpenFile1 As New OpenFileDialog
If (OpenFile1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And (OpenFile1.FileName.Length > 0)) Then
      'do something
End If
```

However, if "do something" is:

```
Dim readText As String = File.ReadAllText(OpenFile1.FileName)
MsgBox(readText)
```

Only the first byte is converted, as the second one is 00 (null) and truncates the rest of the file, marking the end of the string, and it displays only the first byte F0 (≡ in ASCII).

But if I do:

```
'convert file to hex string
Dim bytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFile1.FileName)
Dim hex As String() = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, Function(b) 
b.ToString("X2"))
Dim newfile As String
newfile = (String.Join("", hex))
RichTextBox1.Text = newfile
```

Now the string is properly converted to hex values. So far so good.

[image]

However, when I try to convert the string back to ASCII using this method:

```
 'convert hex string to text and put it into the richtextbox
 Dim asciistring As String = ""
 For x As Integer = 0 To (newfile.Length - 1) Step 2
      Dim k As String = newfile.Substring(x, 2)
      asciistring &= System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(k, 
 16)).ToString()
 Next
 RichTextBox1.Text = asciistring
```

Again, only the first byte is converted. The rest is truncated as soon as it finds a 00 (null).
Is there a way to circumvent this situation?

Comment: No.  You must throw that last snippet away.  This file does not contain text and any attempt to convert it to text will always produce gibberish.  Using a RichTextBox is not sensible either, you can't edit the file content without making it invalid.

Comment: Do you need to just show or also edit those bytes (bytes, not text. Already explained)? If you just need a viewer, you could use the .Net native [ByteViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer) Class, which already implements all of that (again, viewer only).

Comment: @Jimi: What I need is to manipulate newfile (F00000... etc), store it somewhere (e.g. RichTextBox), convert it to binary and save it to file at a later time. I'm stuck in the 'convert to binary' phase.

Comment: @Hans Passant: The RichTextBox doesn't matter. The conversion fails as soon as the first 00 is found, The original file was generated in VB6 using a similar code, but for some reason, it seems that VB.NET does not support it. Can you think of a working code to do the conversion to binary? I mean binary by representing each byte as a text character.

Comment: You cannot modify bytes as they were strings. Forget about the RichTextBox. You can find Hex Editors controls for free if you google around. Maybe, you don't need anything like that. Read the Bytes (File.ReadAllBytes), modify what you need to, then store the new values in a new file (File.WriteAllBytes). Show the bytes as strings if you want, but don't use the strings to save anything. Just for show.

Comment: The conversion does not fail, it has everything to do with the RTB.  Chr(0) is special to controls like that, and the debugger, it is the string terminator in the C language.  Just try to do it explicitly: rtb.Text = "Hello" + Chr(0) + "world".  You only see "Hello".  Gibberish.

Comment: Unlike some languages, VB's has datatypes that are exclusively for text. (Applies, to all .NET languages, Java, JavaScript, SQL, ….)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested out this code yet, but you can try give this method a try :

```
Public Shared Function ConvertHex(ByVal hexString As String) As String
Try
    Dim ascii As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To hexString.Length - 1 Step 2
        Dim hs As String = String.Empty
        hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2)
        Dim decval As UInteger = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)
        Dim character As Char = System.Convert.ToChar(decval)
        ascii += character
    Next

    Return ascii
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

Return String.Empty
End Function
```

When calling the function, just pass your `hex` string.

Comment: Your code is written in C++. I managed to translate it to VB.NET. The code successfully converts 00 (hex) into 0 (dec), but fails to convert 0 into a character (System.Convert.ToChar(decval)). Maybe it's not possible at all, at least in VB.NET.

Comment: @RobinLeBon That's C#, which is another .NET language. (In general, you might find many more examples in C#. Now you know that it's relatively easy to convert if you have to.)

Comment: @RobinLeBon Ok, i posted the VB.Net equivalent of the previous C# code. And it was C#, not C++

Comment: @zack raiyan: Alright C# not C++, missed it by that much. As the other users have said, a string cannot hold a null character. Thanks for the code, anyway.